# Python for loop, print same items once

Tags: python, for-loop

i parse json data from url and then with for loop print items what i want.

```
import urllib.request
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://jsonurl.com')
content = response.read()
jdata = json.loads(content.decode('utf8'))
jdata2 = jdata['available_channels']
for values in jdata2.values():
    live = values['live']
    category = values['category_name']
    if "1" in live:
      print(category)
```

Thing is that if several items have same category then it prints them multiple times.

For example

> Drama Crime Drama Drama Drama Comedy Action Comedy

I would like it to print items that have same category only once:

> Drama,Crime,Comedy,Action

How can i do that?

Comment: Suppose you had to do the task by hand; what would your thought process be with each item? Can you translate that to code?

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the whole code, saw your example `Drama Crime .... ` and thought that was it. set() doesnt work on unhashable objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set to keep track of elements that you have already printed. Example -

```
jdata2 = jdata['available_channels']
seen_set = set()
for values in jdata2.values():
    live = values['live']
    category = values['category_name']
    if "1" in live and category not in seen_set:
      print(category)
      seen_set.add(category)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the categories you’re interested in into a `set` which will remove duplicates. And then print it:

```
wanted_categories = {v['category_name'] for v in jdata2.values() if "1" in v['live']}
print(wanted_categories)
```